# Is a Select query more efficient than a LINQ query on a DataTable?

Tags: c#, linq, select

When I want to perform a query on a DataTable I usually will do something like:

```
myDataTable.Select("myColumnName = 'filterValue');
```

where I can check if this gives any results and so on. However, I could also do something like:

```
// Get the enumerable
IEnumerable<DataRow> myEnumerable = myDataTable.AsEnumerable();

// Setup the query
IEnumerable<DataRow> myQuery =
    from row in myEnumerable
    where row[myColumnNameIndex].ToString() == "filterValue"
    select row;
```

Then get whatever I want from this single query.

I feel the Select method is more efficient since it directly queries the DataTable, whereas the LINQ query first needs a conversion, setup the query, execute the query, etc.

Or is my intuition incorrect? Is the LINQ query optimized in such a way to be more efficient? I am curious because I am writing a method which could use either case and I would like to use the more efficient technique.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: execute both a thousand times, measure time taken and tell us the results, could be interesting.

Comment: We don't speak feelings, we speak in numbers...benchmark and you'll see

Comment: https://chrisbitting.com/2016/05/04/datatable-row-loop-csharp-performance-testing-linq-vs-select-vs-parallel-vs-for/

Comment: @Haytam Your link seems to answer the question, it looks like a LINQ query is more efficient than a simple Select query which is surprising to me, thanks

Comment: I used following : string[] results = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("MyColumnName")).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, cool little one-liner

Comment: While your question is not bad at all, IMHO you better learn when you try it by yourself. Now imagine you expected that Select would work faster, did benchmark and..well the results shows opposite. And, after you added small amount of effort, you post a question...why select is slower than linq alternative. Now that would lead to the other level of answers, with deeper analysis and you would get knowledge from different perspective.

Comment: @Reniuz Very true, I'm running my own benchmarks currently